# RecyclerView лагает скролл при асинхронном добавлении элементов

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

Есть адаптер который добавляет Bitmap в ImageView. Коллекция Bitmap берется из галереи на устройстве.

```
class GalleryAdapter(ctx: Context, private val imagesPath: List<Bitmap>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {
    private val mLayoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        return ItemViewHolder(mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        holder?.imgView?.setImageBitmap(imagesPath[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return imagesPath.size
    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val imgView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageItem)
    }
}
```

Часть самого фрагмента

```
class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {
    private val bitmapList = ArrayList<Bitmap>()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.select_photo_layout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val paths = getImagesPathFromStorage(activity)
        val adapter = GalleryAdapter(context, bitmapList)
        recyclerViewPhoto.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 4)
        recyclerViewPhoto.adapter = adapter
        addAllImg(paths, adapter)
    }

    private fun addAllImg(path: ArrayList<String>, adapter: GalleryAdapter) {
        launch (CommonPool) {
            path.forEach {
                // decodeBitmap это суспенд функция, которая достаёт с устройства Bitmap и подгоняет его по размерам
                bitmapList.add(decodeBitmap(it, 200, 200).await())
                launch (UI) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Работает всё это так, стартует фрагмент, и в `RecyclerView` начинают добавляться фото, и пока они добавляются, скролл ужасно лагает. Лагает до тех пор, пока не добавятся все элементы, после чего скролл становится плавным.

Comment: от куда грузите картинки? покажите метод `getImagesPathFromStorage` и `decodeBitmap`. Сколько у вас всего картинок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно определить проблему поможет [Systrace](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/systrace.html).

Я бы сказал, что основная проблема скрывается в обновлении адаптера, а именно вызове метода `adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Вы пытаетесь после каждого декодинга картинки обновить UI. Я бы отрефакторил этот метод следующим образом:

```
private fun addAllImg(path: ArrayList<String>, adapter: GalleryAdapter) {
    launch (CommonPool) {
        val bitmaps = path.map { decodeBitmap(it, 200, 200) }.toList()
        bitmapList.addAll(bitmaps)
        launch (UI) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Вообще, идеальным вариантом было бы использование [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html). Более того, я бы рассмотрел вариант использования одной из библиотек для отображения изображений - например, [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Дело в том, что вы держите список битмапов в памяти. Каждый битмап занимает достаточное количество памяти, чтобы легко скрашиться с OutOfMemoryError уже на 20 картинке.